Python cx_oracle Cursor.executemany() error - Type Error expecting a number
I am running in to an issue when tryin to run the executemany function. When attempting to insert the rows all together, Type Error is being thrown by Cursor.executeMany stating that a number is expected.
Having an issue with executemany before I tried adding the argument batcherrors=True to the function call but it is still throwing the error.
Sample code:
sql_statement = "insert into table (x, y, z) values (:x, :y, :z)"
cursor.prepare(sql_statement)
cursor.executemany(None, rows_to_be_inserted, batcherrors=True)
for error in Cursor.getbatcherrors()
  print(error.message)

The for loop is never reached as cursor.executemany(None, rows_to_be_inserted, batcherrors=True) throws an error.
However when running the following code, all lines are successfully inserted into the DB
sql_statement = "insert into table (x, y, z) values (:x, :y, :z)"
for row in rows_to_be_inserted:
  cursor.execute(sql_statement, row)


Show us the table schema, and show us the contents of rows_to_be_inserted.

And show actual code & SQL!  Your sample SQL isn't going to work without the commas between column names.

A side comment: don't forget to schedule your upgrade to the latest version of cx_Oracle, which was released under the new name python-oracledb a couple of years ago, see the release announcement.

Thanks for the responses. I am not sure what info I can provide as I am not sure what is internal. This is code that has been passed around a million times so I have no idea who to reach out to internally.
